# Kick-scooters - on topic or off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

I asked a question yesterday about brake blocks for plastic wheels.

[Plastic rims and brake pads](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43727/plastic-rims-and-brake-pads)

At the time it seemed on-topic because its totally bike components.   However not all scooters are built with bikes.

Your thoughts?

Comment: I feel that even if a scooter is not bike components, its still on-topic because scooters and balance bikes are a gateway to proper cycling.

Comment: We're talking about manual kick-scooters, right? Because many people refer to 50 cc. gas powered Vespa types as "scooters".

Comment: @RoboKaren yes - single leg-push scooters.   The ones you're thinking of are essentially motorcycles with an automatic gearbox and belong in https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Criggie Many sit-down scooters have only a single gear ratio. Legally, they're also NOT considered motorcycles. Standing scooters can be gas powered & some exceed 50cc /45MPH, making *them* legally a motorcycle in many municipalities. Standing scooters and seated scooters really need different terms, because referring to one while it's interpreted as the other, leads to "am I insane" levels of confusion. Also, notably, **ebikes are technically a type of electric moped** even though they're not typically perceived as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not overwhelmed with questions about scooters, so I'd be inclined to accept them. I would be less keen on questions about scooting, though I can't imagine there will be many of them ("left or right leg on the platform?", "how can I train for a 100km scoot?").

Comment: 4 km is far enough, and that's with an outboard motor rated at 1 dogpower!

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be against the trend of other answers, but I would NOT allow them.

If we allow scooters, we are on a slippy slope and where do we draw the line? Do you also allow skateboards? Roller skates? Skis?

For me the minumum requirement should be: "must have wheels and pedals" with one clear exception for balance bikes. This includes trikes and uni's whilst ensuring it is something that gets cycled.

Fundamentally the cycle part is why motorbikes are off topic

Comment: Amusing phrasing on that last line! I would change that last line to "Fundamentally, the *pedaling* part is why motorcycles are off topic"... because "motorbikes" is a slang term for "motorcycle" & the "cycle" in bi-cycle & motor-cycle, refers to the two wheels and to having a powered wheel, not to the pedaling.

Answer (score 4):

I would also vote against at least certain kind of questions. In term of use, they somehow compete with bikes (mostly electric shared bikes though), but they are ultimately another class of vehicle.

About the inclusion of the category because some use bike components, it's unlikely that a question asked is actually dependant on the vehicle on which the component is mounted. If a scooter uses bike brake calipers, it's likely that it will be relevant for bikes as well, and should be on-topic (because it's about the component, not the vehicle).

For the rest, the small-wheeled e-ones are being developed from different point of view than bikes: it's an integrated package where it would be hard to have the same kind of questions that we typically see here.

Comment: Perhaps a mobilityvehicle.stackexchange?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps kick scooters are something like 30-40% on-topic for this SE site. The exact percentage doesn't matter as much as the contentions that:

1. The world isn't always black and white. It can help to think of things in shades of grey.
2. I think that kick scooters aren't clearly on-topic for Bicycles SE. The FAQ does limit it to wheeled vehicles that are exclusively or mainly pedal-powered.
3. However, kick scooters share some similarity with bicycles. They are human-powered. They move at similar speeds. The motor skills required to operate them have some similarities with bikes. There may be some crossover in components and equipment, e.g. bearings, cargo equipment.
4. I bet most people would consider balance bikes to be on topic. These are learning tools for children. Kick scooters are more similar to balance bikes than they are to standard bicycles. It is obviously possible to go too far with analogies, so you need some sort of limiting principle eventually.
5. Kick scooters may be in a grey area between bicycles and not-bicycles. I think I would be fine admitting them despite them not being as much like bicycles as unicycles, handcycles, balance bikes, etc.
6. Point 5 may change with circumstances, e.g. if kick scooters really take off in popularity and we get flooded with enough questions that people start wondering if they deserve their own SE site.

Answer (score 1):

Kick scooters should be on-topic.  Bicycles stack exchange is not limited to the narrow definition of two-wheeled, single track human pedal powered vehicles.  We already have questions about [unicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unicycle), [tricycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tricycle), and [handcycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handcycle).  Unicycles are one wheel short of being a bicycle, tricycles have one bonus wheel compared to a bicycle, handcycles are not strictly bicycles either, and kick scooters lack pedals.  But as a community, we should welcome kick scooters as part of the wider family of variations on the bicycle that we can see on the road.

[image: Kick scooter]
*Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Travelling_with_kickbike.JPG)*

I created the [kick-scooter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kick-scooter) tag to cover such questions.

Comment: Wiki says a bicycle is pedal driven: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle
Dictionaries also define it as having pedals: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bicycle

Comment: @AndyP unicycles and trikes are already on-topic, so clearly we're not limited to that definition.

Comment: I was responding to this "Who says bicycles need to have pedals" part.
It cant be a bicycle if you dont cycle it

Comment: @AndyP OK, fair enough.  I have rephrased.